# $_SESSION variables sometimes not working for login system

Tags: php, session, authentication

First of all, I'm a little bit at a wits end. I've been scouring the net for solutions and can find nothing but dead trail that don't seem to help. I am an amateur developer working on a large and established website.

The following code snippets show our login system.

**HTML Login**

```
    <form action="/script.php" method="post" id="loginvbform">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="function" value="Login" />
        <input type="submit" id="logins" value="<?php echo $t['loginbox_login']?>" />
        <input type="text" class="logininput" name="name" placeholder="<?php echo $t['general_username']?>" required="required" /><br />
        <input type="password" class="logininput" name="pass" placeholder="<?php echo $t['general_password'];?>" required="required" /><br />
    </div>
    </form>

    <p><a href="/forgotpass.php"><?php echo $t['loginbox_forgot_password'];?></a> | <a href="/register.php"><?php echo $t['loginbox_register'];?></a></p>
</div>
```

**Script file (relevant function)**

```
// Remove spaces from the entered username, so that the few péople with former spaces can login without problems
$p_name = str_replace(' ', '', $p_name);
echo $p_name;
$user_info = db_get_result(db_query("SELECT user_id, username, pword, auth_verified, user_status, pword_new FROM users WHERE username = '$p_name'"));
$user_found = false;


if($user_info == null)                                                    $cs->WriteNote(false, $t['login_error'], $t['login_error_faulty_username']);
else if(isset($user_info['pword_new'])) if(password_verify("$pass", $user_info['pword_new']))                $cs->WriteNote(false, $t['login_error'], str_replace(array('[link_resetpassword]', '[/link]'), array('<a href="/forgotpass.php">', '</a>'), $t['login_error_wrong_password']));
else if($user_info['pword'] != md5($pass))                                $cs->WriteNote(false, $t['login_error'], str_replace(array('[link_resetpassword]', '[/link]'), array('<a href="/forgotpass.php">', '</a>'), $t['login_error_wrong_password']));
else if($user_info['user_status'] == 0)                                   $cs->WriteNote(false, $t['login_error'], str_replace(array('[link_contact]', '[/link]'), array('<a href="/support.php">', '</a>'), $t['login_error_user_suspended']));

// Everything is fine, we can log this user in
else
{
    // in January 2016, we upgraded password security. In order to do this, we needed to force all users to log-in again so that we could hash their passwords from the raw password. This code does the hashing if they have no updated password hash.
    if(empty($user_info['pword_new']))
    {

        $pword_new = password_hash("$pass", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
        db_query("UPDATE users SET pword_new = '$pword_new' WHERE username = '$p_name'");
     }  

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_info['user_id'];
    $cs->WriteNote(true, $t['login_success']);
    $user_found = true;
    $redirect = "/user/" . $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

if(!$user_found)    { sleep(4);}
```

**Checking for login (this file is loaded on every single page)**

```
session_start(); 

...


 if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{


    if(is_numeric($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {

    $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        $login_data = db_get_result(db_query("SELECT * FROM users JOIN skins USING(skin_id) 
                                            WHERE users.user_id = $uid AND users.user_status > 0"));
        if($login_data)
        {
            $logged_in      = true;
            $user_id        = $uid;

*****Then there's some personal user data related stuff that you don't need to see*****

        }
    }
}
```

Now on to the issue.

SOMETIMES, this system doesn't work. The several instances of `$cs->WriteNote` functions are used to write error messages and login notifications to the user in this case, however when the login system fails, none of these are displayed. This system works flawlessly like 85% of the time.

Browser does not appear to play a part, as people have reported this bug on Chrome, Firefox, Edge (idk about Opera). Browsers with cookies allowed still experience this bug.

Even when logins fail, the `$redirect = "/user/" . $_SESSION['user_id'];` is actually set correctly and redirects to the correct page, however the session does not preserve through the redirect.

I have locked the website so that every page must use the www. domain, as I thought that may be the issue. It does not appear to help.

The following is our php configuration regarding sessions:

**Directive | Local Value | Master Value**

```
session.auto_start  Off Off

session.cache_expire    180 180

session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache

session.cookie_domain   no value    no value

session.cookie_httponly Off Off

session.cookie_lifetime 0   0

session.cookie_path /   /

session.cookie_secure   Off Off

session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom

session.entropy_length  32  32

session.gc_divisor  1000    1000

session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440

session.gc_probability  1   1

session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5

session.hash_function   0   0

session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID

session.referer_check   no value    no value

session.save_handler    files   files

session.save_path   no value    no value

session.serialize_handler   php php

session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On

session.upload_progress.enabled On  On

session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%

session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1

session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS

session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_

session.use_cookies On  On

session.use_only_cookies    On  On

session.use_strict_mode Off Off

session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

If you need more information, feel free to ask and I'll do my best to divulge.

Does anybody have any idea on the reasoning that our login system isn't working SOMETIMES?

Comment: `session_start();` on top of each `php` page just after starting `<?php` is needed to work with `SESSION`

Comment: `session_start();` is already at the top of each page. Sorry, I must have forgotten to put that in!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in the beginning of each page.

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Comment: `session_start();` is already at the top of each page. Sorry, I must have forgotten to put that in!